# Setting up svnserve as a service on RHEL5/CentOS system

Tags: centos, svn, redhat, svnserve

How can I configure svnserve to run as a service.

```
svnserve -d -r /var/svn/
```

just works until the server is restarted.

---

Edit1: server details

```
root@vps [~]# uname -a
Linux vps.example.com 2.6.18-028stab070.14 #1 SMP Thu Nov 18 16:04:02 MSK 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've not already got a script for starting the service in /etc/init.d, create one, then add links in the relevant runlevel dirs.

The process is described at http://queens.db.toronto.edu/~nilesh/linux/subversion-howto/

Comment: I am looking at the sample script, but (1) I dont run it under any 'svn'-specific user. Currently I've been running svnserve -d ... as root. (2) I dont think I have the file startproc anywhere on my system.

Comment: any thoughts on how i can do this?

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to get it going would be to add the startup command to `/etc/rc.local/`. This is run at the end of the system boot.

The "proper" way is to use the init system. There's a file called `/etc/init.d/skeleton` which is a basic framework for making an init script for starting a service. Copy it to /etc/init.d/svnserve and customise it as needed. There's also plenty of examples of svnserve init files on the web. Once `/etc/init.d/svnserver [start|stop]` works as expected, you can then run `chkconfig svnserve on`. This init script will be then be started on boot, and stopped on shutdown.

Comment: Hi @Niall - the file doesnt exist on the rhel/centos system that I have...

Comment: Sorry, should be /etc/init.d/skeleton! Main post updated.

Comment: Hmm... root@vps [~]# find / -name 'skeleton' didnt find anything

Comment: any alternate thoughts?

Comment: hmm, looks like /etc/init.d/skeleton is a Debian thing! The best bet is to look for the many svnserve init scripts available on the web, for example: http://www.mygeekproject.com/?p=152

Answer (score 1):

[Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) may be the easiest way to do this. It's available in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), a high-quality 3rd party repository of packages for RHEL/CentOS.

```
rpm -ivh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
yum install supervisor
chkconfig --levels 345 supervisor on
```

Edit /etc/supervisord.conf according the [docs](http://supervisord.org/running.html#adding-a-program).

```
service start supervisor
```

Answer (score 1):

To start svnserve at runlevel 3,4 and 5 try this :

```
chkconfig --level 345 svnserve on
```

To check if it's OK :

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep *svn*
```

[image: Screenshot for systemctl list-unit-files | grep *svn*]

Note : before chkconfig you can check if service file already exists:

```
ls  /usr/lib/systemd/system/*svn*
```

[image: screenshot for ls /usr/lib/systemd/system/*svn*]